# Getting Error "The conversion of the varchar value '6160382514d97' overflowed an int column" in an SSIS Package

Tags: sql, ssis, visual-studio-2019

I have been searching for a solution to this and haven't had any luck.

I have an SSIS package which is loading data from one table and after some lookups, etc. writes it out to another table.
The above error is occurring during the first step of the Data Flow which is an OLEDB Source (SQL 2016 db).
The column in question is an nvarchar(250) and there is nothing that changes it to an int at any point.

I'm thinking that it must be some sort of implicit conversion, but why when it is nvarchar all the way through?

I'm pulling my hair out with this, does anyone have any ideas please?

[image: Data Flow]

[image: Error Message]

[image: Source and Destination Metadata]

Comment: Post a picture of your data flow please. The error message(s) should indicate the component that is generating the conversion error. For extra points, double click the connector line out of the source and get a picture of the values in the Metadata tab and repeat that on the line that leads into the destination.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me @billingc. I'm having some issues adding images. I'll figure out how to do it and upload them.

Comment: @billinkc I've added the screenshots to my original post.

Comment: This seems to be an intermittent problem that allows these types of values through most of the time, but trips up for some, as yet unknown, reason.

Comment: Do you have more than one data flow within the package?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the responses.
The issue seems to have been a buffer size issue with with a lookup task.
When I checked the lookup table, it didn't have an appropriate index. I have added one and it seems to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes SSIS keep the old metadata with the auto-convert.

I suggest that you delete your ole Db source component and rebuild a new with your select. Moreover you can go to advenced option (right click on the source component and in the last tab you can validate the datatype of your column and adapt to varchar if it is integer.